# ListView without hover and selected style but with alternating listviewitem color style

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I try to create a `ListView` which doesn't have a hover and selected style but has alternating colors for the `ListViewItem`'s.

To disable the styles I set the `ItemContainerStyle`. The problem is that the expression `ListView.AlternationIndex` is somehow allways evaluating to `0` as `Christian Mosers` `WPF Inspector` tells me. This results in that the background color for all items is red.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Configuration}" AlternationCount="2" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border>
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="ListView.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="ListView.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>

                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

How can I color the items alternating wihout having the selected and hover style?

- (The background color of the first item should be red the one of the second blue the one of the third red again and so on)
- (The Backgroundcolor, border, padding, margin and so on should not change when the mouse is over an `ListViewItem` or a `ListViewItem` is selected)

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. I changed added a template binding to the solution to get rid of the `Name` property.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Configuration}" AlternationCount="2" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ListBox.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ListBox.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Do you really just want to disable the selection style or do you actually not need the selection functionality at all? You may as well revert to an `ItemsControl` if you just want to display a dynamic stack of items.

Comment: @grek40 I need the selection functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggers have to be on the control template; the Border doesn't know anything about its parent.

But since the property to set (Background) is on the Border, you have to name it and use TargetName.

```
<ListView AlternationCount="2" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border Name="border">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Red" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Blue" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListViewItem Content="ABC"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="DEF"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="GHI"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="JKL"/>
</ListView>
```

This XAML produces the desired result: [image]

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and the one I posted? Why did you undelete your previous answer and basically copied mine...?

Comment: I didn't copy your. I deleted mine because I didn't read the question correctly. I then went on to VS to test another solution, which happened to be the same as your. This is why, by the way, I don't have OP's binding in mine, and actual test data.

Answer (score 1):

Put the triggers in `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Configuration}" AlternationCount="2" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="Border" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" TargetName="Border" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```